# How to make another request to another attribute (develops_in) of an array?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working with an Age Of Empire II API (https://age-of-empires-2-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/technologies) and there are requests that require another additional request, such as develops_in and applies_to

The problem is that I don't know how to show that data .... I know that you have to enter the array technologies, look for develop_in, take the url and make another request again
And then I must show the data in a new view, in a second table using modal or pop up ...
But also, develops_in contains string that are information and not url and in the case of applies_to it contains two url that you must use request.
I will leave information on how I have shown the data in the first table (this is done with MatTable).

The address of this API is: https://age-of-empires-2-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/structure/archery_range

But anyway add an image with the content.

**technologies.model.ts**

```
export class Technologies {
    id: number; 
    name: string; 
    description: string; 
    expansion: string;
    age: string;
    develops_in: string;
    cost: string;
    build_time: number;
    applies_to: [];
}
```

**technologies.component.ts**

```
export class TechnologiesComponent implements OnInit {

  technologies: Technologies[] = [];
  tech: Technologies;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'expansion', 'age', 'cost', 'build_time'];
  dataSource : any;

  constructor(private gameService: GameService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.gameService.getTechnologies().subscribe(
      res => {
        let x;
        x=res['technologies'];

        x.forEach(element => {
          this.tech = new Technologies();
          this.tech.id = element['id'];
          this.tech.name = element['name'];
          this.tech.description = element['description'];
          this.tech.expansion = element['expansion'];
          this.tech.age = element['age'];
          this.tech.build_time = element['build_time'];
          this.technologies.push(this.tech);              
        });
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
        this.dataSource.data = this.technologies;
      },
      err => console.error(err)
    );
  }
}
```

**technologies.component.html**

```
<div class="container mat-elevation-z8">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="table-container">

        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> id</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Nombre </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Descripción </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.description}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="expansion">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Expansión </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.expansion}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="age">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Era </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.age}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="cost">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Costo </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.cost}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="build_time">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Tiempo de Construcción</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.build_time}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

[image: Array technologies API]

Comment: hi, Brother, i will  help you can you provide more details on what you trying to do

Comment: I am making a web application that shows the data of the game Age Of Empire II (API). The data of technologies, units, structures and civilizations. Which I do with the help of MatTable

Comment: you also making pagination thig

Comment: @harkeshkumar You are in this git repository [https://gitlab.com/silvatapialuis/test-aoe-ii.git]

Comment: wait brother  i let me ckeck

Comment: @harkeshkumar 
i'm using routing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204589/discussion-between-harkesh-kumar-and-luis-fernando-silva).

Comment: @harkeshkumar... Are you there?

Comment: hi are you there

Comment: Hi! @harkeshkumar

Comment: its done and to commit  i need to have user name and password

Comment: Why?  If you are a maintainer in the repository

Comment: you i can push code that i made or you can get from answer you choices brother

Comment: @harkeshkumar Is the code in git?

Comment: @harkeshkumar 
I sent you a message in the chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***New Technology Html Code***

```
        <ng-container matColumnDef="name" sticky>
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Nombre </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="Agent">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Agent </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Agent}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="expansion">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Expansión </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.expansion}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="age">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Era </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.age}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="cost">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Costo </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                {{'Madera: ' + (element.cost.Wood || '0')}}<br>
                {{'Comida: ' + (element.cost.Food || '0')}}<br>
                {{'Oro: ' + (element.cost.Gold || '0')}}<br>
                {{'Piedra: ' + (element.cost.Stone || '0')}}<br>
            </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="build_time">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Tiempo de Construcción</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.build_time}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="hit_points">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> hit_points</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.hit_points}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="line_of_sight">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> line_of_sight</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.line_of_sight}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="armor">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> armor</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.armor}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="special">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> special</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.special}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**New Technology.ts  code**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Technologies } from '../models/technologies.model';
import { MatTableDataSource, MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
import { GameService } from 'src/app/services/game.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-technology',
  templateUrl: './technology.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./technology.component.css']
})
export class TechnologyComponent implements OnInit {

  technologies: Technologies[] = [];
  tech: Technologies;


  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'name',
    'expansion',
    'Agent',
    'cost',
    'build_time',
    'hit_points',
    'line_of_sight',
    'armor',
    'special'
  ];
  dataSource : any;


  constructor(private gameService: GameService, public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<TechnologyComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }


  ngOnInit() {

    this.gameService.fetchTechnology(this.data.url)
    .subscribe((res)=>{
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
      this.dataSource.data =res;


    })
  }
}
```

***Technology Html Page***

```
<div class="container mat-elevation-z8">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="table-container">

        <ng-container matColumnDef="name" sticky>
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Nombre </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Descripción </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.description}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="expansion">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Expansión </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.expansion}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="age">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Era </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.age}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="cost">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Costo </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                {{'Madera: ' + (element.cost.Wood || '0')}}<br>
                {{'Comida: ' + (element.cost.Food || '0')}}<br>
                {{'Oro: ' + (element.cost.Gold || '0')}}<br>
                {{'Piedra: ' + (element.cost.Stone || '0')}}<br>
            </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="build_time">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Tiempo de Construcción</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.build_time}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="develops_in">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> develops_in</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> <button  mat-button color="primary" (click)="openDialog(element.develops_in)">view</button><!-- {{element.develops_in}} --> </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

***technologies.ts code***

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GameService } from '../../services/game.service';
import { Technologies } from '../models/technologies.model';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material';
import { TechnologyComponent } from '../technology/technology.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-technologies',
  templateUrl: './technologies.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./technologies.component.css']
})
export class TechnologiesComponent implements OnInit {

  technologies: Technologies[] = [];
  tech: Technologies;
  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'name', 
    'description', 
    'expansion', 
    'age', 
    'cost', 
    'build_time',
    'develops_in'
  ];
  dataSource : any;

  constructor(private gameService: GameService, public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.gameService.getTechnologies().subscribe(
      res => {
        let x;
        x=res['technologies'];

        x.forEach(element => {
          this.tech = new Technologies();
          this.tech.name = element['name'];
          this.tech.description = element['description'];
          this.tech.expansion = element['expansion'];
          this.tech.age = element['age'];
          this.tech.cost = element['cost'];
          this.tech.build_time = element['build_time'];
          this.tech.develops_in = element['develops_in'];

          this.technologies.push(this.tech);              
        });
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
        this.dataSource.data = this.technologies;
      },
      err => console.error(err)
    );
  }



  openDialog(link:string): void {
    console.log(link);
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(TechnologyComponent, {
      width: '950px', height:'500px',
      data: {url:link}
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');

    });
  }

}
```

Comment: I sent you a message in the chat

Comment: There are things I do not understand, for example the fetchTechnology method

Comment: i push on git you can pull it and please your question about fetchtechnology

Comment: Hello... I hava a question.... I'm trying to do the same procedure in another component but it appears an message saying ERROR TypeError... What could it be the reason?

Comment: sorry I am getting what you trying to say

Comment: can you console log in DevelopsInComponent ngOnInit()   as 1st line  and tell what its showing

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: wait let me tak a pull and check

Comment: so what's the mistake?

Comment: i dont know what will be the issue but if you can tell me how you get this message then i can help you

Comment: I am doing the same query that we did before, but in the civilization component. I use the same method as before, but I changed the name to fetch. And if I do it in Technologies it works well

Comment: now i got your issue wait i will find out and fix it

Comment: take a pull from git and your issue is fix

Comment: Why does it take the [0] ?? ... And it doesn't show the table data

Comment: you send array not string as a link  so i use first index of that array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59508489/how-to-use-input-output

Comment: Do you know about @Input () and @Output?